# Flutter Chrome extension Clipboard access

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am tryin to build a chrome extension in flutter and need access to clipboard for copy and paste options, i am using Clipboard.getData() for copy and clipboard.setData() for paste. The paste function works perfectly but when i try to use getData it shows "permission denied" error.
Also when i compile the code for web. and then try to copy text from clipboard using getData, it first give me a popup in browser that asks me to allow access to make copy and paste operations to the clipboard and after the permission is granted copy operation works.
But as chrome extension do not give such popup, it directly shows me the error

What needs to be changed to get the access to clipboard for the chrome extension?

I am expecting the chrome extension to be able to copy data from clipboard

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered this problem and I believe this should be related to the permission for your extension.
Can you confirm if you have the permission clipboardRead in your manifest?
Here is where to place it.

```
    {
     "manifest_version": 1,
     "name": "Name of extension",
     "version": "1.0",
     "description": "Description",
     "permissions": [
       "clipboardRead",
       "clipboardWrite"
     ],...}
```

Comment: Yes, i have added these permissions in my manifest file, also it my extension details it shows me that permissions required are read and write, which is essentially correct but when i try to copy something using a button press it throws a permission denied error!!

Comment: Can you please provide more context on the OS you are using weather testing on debug mode?
Also if possible, can you explain how to reproduce and I will be happy to debug and get back to you

Comment: i am facing same issue with Pasteboard.image. it works on web app by giving permission popup by on the extension it returns null. did it work for you Parth?

Comment: my issue is resolved as mention in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Add permission from extension settings in "View Web Permissions". Change "Clipboard permission" from "Ask" to "Allow".

Answer (score 0):

add the following code in your `content-script.js`

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.allow='clipboard-read; clipboard-write';
iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html");

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**